# Streaming files with PHP logic

Tags: php, streaming

On our website, users can upload mp3 audio and mp4 video medias. They can also set a private/public flag on them to deny access to other users than them.

We want to stream these medias and display them with some Javascript players, but since we need to execute some PHP logic, we cannot let the web server stream them.

What is an efficient way to stream those medias and being able to execute some PHP logic before (to grant or deny access) ?

Comment: simple. php script validates the hit. if it's ok, it streams out the content. if it's not, it streams out nothing, or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd written and tested this script for *downloads*. Should work well with streaming too.

```
$file_name = $_GET['file'];
/* define UPLOADS_DIR */
$file_path = UPLOADS_DIR . $file_name;

if (!is_file($file_path)) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
    exit;
}

/* define has_access */
if (!has_access($file_name)) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit;
}

$file = fopen($file_path, 'rb');

if (!$file) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error');
    exit;
}

$file_size = filesize($file_path);

$start = 0;
$end = $file_size - 1;
$length = $file_size;

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {

    if (!preg_match('/^bytes=(\d*)-(\d*)/', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], $matches) || ($matches[1] === '' && $matches[2] === '')) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
        fclose($file);
        exit;
    }

    $start = (int)$matches[1];
    $end = $matches[2] === '' ? $file_size - 1 : (int)$matches[2];

    if ($start >= $end || $end >= $file_size) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
        fclose($file);
        exit;
    }

    $length = $end - $start + 1;
}

if ($length != $file_size) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
    header('Content-Range: bytes ' . $start . '-' . $end . '/' . $file_size);
}
else {
    header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
}

header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: -1');
header('Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $file_name . '"');
header('Content-Length: ' . $length);

set_time_limit(0);

/* you can modify the chunk size */
$chunk_size = 1024 * 8;

fseek($file, $start);
$left = $length;

while ($left > 0) {

    $size = $chunk_size > $left ? $left : $chunk_size;

    echo fread($file, $size);
    ob_flush();
    flush();

    if (connection_status()) {
        fclose($file);
        exit;
    }

    $left -= $size;
}

fclose($file);
```